# Theoremstyle: Definitions, Theorems with angled brackets

Tags: citing

I have a small problem to solve:

I want to cite where i have my definitions/theorems from e.g.

> 1.2 Definition [1, Theorem 1.2]

How do i do that? When i use

```
    \cite{XY}
```

then it will appear a number with angled brackets: [1]
When i use

```
    \begin{definition}{\cite{XY), Theorem 1.2}
```

it will appear

> 1.2 Definition ([1], Theorem 1.2)

I am very thankful for any help!

Comment: `{\cite[Theorem 1.2]{xy}}`

Answer (score 1):

`\cite[Theorem 1.2]{XY}` should work in typical cases.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me, but now it is displaced unter "Definition", not in at the right from it :/ Is there any alternative?

Comment: I just changes my environmentdefs, now it works. Thanks you two !